# How to specify the path address for bibliography?

Tags: latex, bibliography

In LaTeX, the code

```
\bibliography{/Users/Name/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Academic/Research/Bibliography/Bib.bib}{}
```

does not render the reference list. When I use

```
\bibliography{/Users/Name/Library/Bib.bib}{}
```

it does. So I thought the problem is the space in "Mobile Documents". Therefore I used

```
\bibliography{"/Users/Name/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Academic/Research/Bibliography/Bib.bib"}{}
```

and it does not work. Where am I making the mistake?

Comment: Where is your latex document located in relation to the bib file? Maybe a relative path could help.

Comment: It is located in some folder that is not in the same folder as the bib file. What is a relative path?

Comment: A relative path describes how you get from one folder to another. For example if your tex document would be in `/Users/Name/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Academic/Research/foo/bar/`, then the relative path to the bib file would be `../../Bibliography/Bib.bib`, thus avoiding all special letters

Comment: I just tried \bibliography{../../Bibliography/Bib}{} and it did not work. I do not understand how this is supposed to work. Without giving the address, how does tex supposed to find the bib file.

Comment: This was just an example because I don't know where your tex file is located. I asked where it is located, but unfortunately got no answer.

Comment: It is located at /Users/name/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Academic/Research/Papers/16/Paper/Paper.tex

Comment: Try with `\bibliography{../../../Bibliography/Bib}`

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much. I wanted to accept it as answer but cannot seem to figure out how. I think it is because the answer is given in comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid all possible conflicts with special characters like spaces and ~, you could use a relative path. In your specific case this would mean

```
\bibliography{../../../Bibliography/Bib}
```

which means going 3 directories upwards and then into the `Bibliography` folder.